# How to write Oracle query to group like below?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, gaps-and-islands

```
Id value 
1 5
1 6
1 8
1 9
1 10
```

Result should be like below

```
Id minValue maxValue
1   5               6
1   8               10
```

Previous value difference should be 1 otherwise need to insert other row

Comment: Are you using Oracle or MySQL?

Comment: How come you don't want value 9 returned? Gaps and islands problem?

Comment: What have you tried so far ..?

Comment: @jarlh we are using Oracle

Comment: @barbaros I got the solution using looping and inserting to temp table but I want to achieve it using GROUPBY or something in direct way

Comment: well, please edit the question with your attempt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is famous GAPS and ISLANDS problem. You can read [this](https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/category/gaps-and-islands/) wonderful article from [Lalit Kumar B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3989608/lalit-kumar-b) for detailed description. You can try below query -

```
SELECT id, MIN(value), MAX(value)
FROM (SELECT id, value, value - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY value) rn
      FROM test) T
GROUP BY id, rn;
```

Here is the [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7f851a653451dbfca6194b3950db11a4)

Comment: You need to partition by the ID in the `row_number()` or [it can get confused](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8fd1dc7d2c97531cccd4b04992249c17). It will also get confused by duplicate values for the same ID, but the question doesn't show that happening so may not be an issue.

Comment: @AlexPoole, Completely agreed and updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you subtract the position of each value within the list of values for that ID (which you can get with an analytic function) from the value itself:

```
value - dense_rank() over (partition by id order by value)
```

then consecutive (or duplicate) values will get the same result:

```
select id, value,
  value - dense_rank() over (partition by id order by value)
from your_table;

        ID      VALUE        GRP
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          5          4
         1          6          4
         1          8          5
         1          9          5
         1         10          5
```

You can then aggregate using those differences:

```
select id, min(value) as minvalue, max(value) as maxvalue
from (
  select id, value,
    value - dense_rank() over (partition by id order by value) as grp
  from your_table
)
group by id, grp
order by id, minvalue;

        ID   MINVALUE   MAXVALUE
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          5          6
         1          8         10
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2b850f9b9d75799d9566dae1a0a411b2)

You could use [`row_number()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions156.htm) instead of [`dense_rank()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions052.htm) if there are no duplicates.